# How can I change Excels default XML output encoding?

Tags: xml, excel, encoding, export

I'm working on a solution where Excel data is exported to XML. I've implemented a schema and I get all the data exported properly. The one problem I have is that the solution that will receive the XML files expects ISO-8859-1 encoding, while Excel by default outputs UTF-8.

Is there any way to change this?

Oh, and I'm using the xml export feature in Excel 2007.

In advance, thanks for all replies.

Best regards,
André GUlbrandsen

Answer (score 0):

I am using Excel 2010 and there is a settings at File > Options > Advanced > Web Options > Encoding. You can set the output encoding out there. Hope it helps!

Comment: This didn't work for me. I always get UTF-8 no matter what I select. This did change it when saving as html, though.

Comment: Edit: Excel Only exports to UTF-8:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-XML-in-Excel-f11faa7e-63ae-4166-b3ac-c9e9752a7d80?CorrelationId=e99278a5-afa8-43b6-8c42-8253f128ea07&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US 

says so.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Excel only exports XML encoded as UTF-8. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-XML-in-Excel-f11faa7e-63ae-4166-b3ac-c9e9752a7d80?CorrelationId=e99278a5-afa8-43b6-8c42-8253f128ea07&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bmexport